# Rolling upgrades of a Playframework application

Tags: playframework

Considering a PlayFramework application using Akka and WebSocket.

For the moment, I have only one server. When I deploy a new version, I have to stop the server, deploy and restart. Not very customer friendly, isn't it…

I wonder the easiest/cheapest way to perform a rolling upgrade ?

Just having two separate instances of my application running and using a LB won't do the trick due to states owned by actors…

Comment: You have more than one server? How are requests distributed to them (nginx, haproxy, etc)?